# Keycloak return Invalid parameter: redirect_uri

Tags: java, spring-security, keycloak, spring-oauth2

I am trying to run some simple app by using spring boot and keycloak. App running on localhost:80. Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>testOfKeyCloack</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
        <springboot.plugin.version>2.1.4.RELEASE</springboot.plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${springboot.plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

There is my application.yml, where keycloak listening port 8080 on localhost.
Also there is realm - WebReport and client testK:

```
server:
  port: "80"
spring:
  application.name: ${APPLICATION_NAME:spring-security-keycloak-oauth}
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:8080/realms/webReport
        registration:
          keycloak:
            client-id: testK
```

Valid redirect URI: http://localhost:80/*

For test I use controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class SampleController {

    @GetMapping("/anonymous")
    public String getAnonymousInfo() {
        return "Anonymous";
    }

    @GetMapping("/user")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    public String getUserInfo() {
        return "user info";
    }

    @GetMapping("/admin")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public String getAdminInfo() {
        return "admin info";
    }

    @GetMapping("/service")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('SERVICE')")
    public String getServiceInfo() {
        return "service info";
    }

    @GetMapping("/me")
    public Object getMe() {
        final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return authentication.getName();
    }
}
```

And this is my WebSecurityConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                        .antMatchers("/api/anonymous/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login(oauth2Login -> oauth2Login
                        .userInfoEndpoint(userInfoEndpoint -> userInfoEndpoint
                                .oidcUserService(this.oidcUserService())
                        )
                );

    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oidcUserService() {
        final OidcUserService delegate = new OidcUserService();

        return (userRequest) -> {
            OidcUser oidcUser = delegate.loadUser(userRequest);

            final Map<String, Object> claims = oidcUser.getClaims();
            final JSONArray groups = (JSONArray) claims.get("groups");

            final Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = groups.stream()
                    .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(("ROLE_" + role)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

            return new DefaultOidcUser(mappedAuthorities, oidcUser.getIdToken(), oidcUser.getUserInfo());
        };
    }
}
```

But when I try to go for example to : "http://localhost:80/api/admin"
I am getting an error: "Invalid parameter: redirect_uri"
Console output: "GET http://localhost:8080/realms/webReport/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=my_webreport&state=*** redirect_uri=http://localhost/login/oauth2/code/keycloak 400 (Bad Request)"

Advices from other threads didn't help, so I just don't know, what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're saying you set your redirect URIs for the client to `http://localhost:80/*`.

Then you made this request: `GET http://localhost:8080/realms/webReport/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=my_webreport&state=*** redirect_uri=http://localhost:8084/login/oauth2/code/keycloak`.

`http://localhost:8084/login/oauth2/code/keycloak` is not matched by `http://localhost:80/*`, the port needs to match the actual port of your request.

Comment: Sorry. I modified my question. Request was auto-generated by keycloak. And now redirect_uri = http://localhost/login/oauth2/code/keycloak, but I am getting error "Invalid parameter: redirect_uri" again

Comment: Well, the problem remains the same: There is a mismatch between the redirect_uri that is being requested by the application, and the redirect_uri that Keycloak is configured to accept. If you include the port explicitly in your valid redirect URIs in Keycloak, then it needs to be part of the redirect_uri requested.

Comment: port 80 is default, so its not displayed in request.

Comment: Yes, but the check on redirect_uri is a *string match*. It is not aware of the fact that 80 is the default port for http. "http://localhost:80/*" does not match "http://localhost/login/oauth2/code/keycloak". "http://localhost/*" would be a match.